# Request the keyboard focus from a QML-Rectangle in c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

currently I am trying to set the key-board focus of a simple QML-rectangle in c++. A sample:

```
Rectangle {
    Keys.onUpPressed: {
        console.log( 'Key up was pressed');
    }   
}
```

If the control has the focus I should be able to see the message in the log. In c++ I found the instance and just tried to write the focus-property:

```
    if ( true == QQmlProperty::write( pInstance, "focus", newFocus ) ) {
        qDebug() << "Set new focus successful";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Set new focus failed";
    }
```

So the property write was successfully. But I am not able to see the message caused by my QML-code, when my control has the key-board focus. Any ideas how I can get the focus. The idea behind this is to control which element get's the key-board system on startup.

Kim Kulling

Answer (score 2):

Export a boolean property from your C++ object and bind the focus property in your qml item to  the property on your C++ object. This way you will not be forcing your C++ code to assume anything about your UI.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I just called forceActiveFocus() for my item.

Kim